# How to Disable touch on Action bar

Tags: android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I want to disable touch event on action bar. Suggest me how to do it.
Note:I dont want to remove the action bar, I needs to be there, but should not be touchable.

I have tried this in my activity:

```
ActionBar ab = ((myActivity != null)? myActivity.getActionBar() : null);
if(ab ! = null) {
    View v= ab.getCustomView();
}
if (v != null) {
   v.setClickable(false);
   v.setFocusable(false);  
}
```

but it did not work.
Please sugges something.
Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by making an invisible view over the entire activity.
and then punched a hole through some portion where if touched i coud dispatch the event to the main activity which is actually behind the invisible view activity,

```
getOwnerActivity().dispatchTouchEvent(event);
```